# What are the various ways to backup an MySQL server?

Tags: solaris, mysql

I am trying to figure out how someone backed up our database. We had a person working for us who was able to backup the database on a server without having mysql client or mysqldump installed on the server.  I can find the .sql files created by the dumps he made, but I can not figure out what he did to create them.   It's a Solaris server with coolstack mysql server installed on it.   I'd really like to be able to replicate  what he was doing.

Comment: Listing all the possible ways to generate `.sql` files from the contents of a database is the very definition of "too broad" -- Your best bet is to contact your former employee and ask them what they did...

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the backup was being run on the same machine as the database server? mysqldump is quite happy connecting to a remote database and backing it up that way.

The other question I'd have is whether it makes sense to replicate a method of backing up which isn't easily understood, especially if that data is valuable. The last thing you want when restoring a dead server is confusion!